# How do I trigger ajax validation when a button is pressed?

Tags: ajax, yii

I am using the Yii CActiveForm widget to create a form.  On the same page, but separate from the form, I have a button that pops up a JQuery modal dialog box.

Here's what I would like to do (but cannot figure out how to do):  When the button is pressed, I would like to validate the form using Ajax before popping up the modal dialog box.  If the form has an error, I would like to display all the errors and prevent the modal dialog from opening.  If there are no errors, then the modal dialog box should open.

How can I call the Yii ajax validation from within a button click event?

Comment: You can submit a form by click and then use [afterValidate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#clientOptions-detail) to check if there was an error.

Comment: I am hoping to do it all in Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: In `afterValidate` you should specify the name of JS function that will be triggered after validation. Check the docs.

Comment: Got it.  There is an afterValidate option for the CActiveForm widget.  This can be used to run a some javascript code after validating. http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8822-ajaxsubmitbutton-returning-success-instead-of-error/page__view__findpost__p__59621